# a cuda kernel with two different threads indexes

Tags: c++, cuda

I am writing a kernel in CUDA that uses two different threads. here is How the scenario goes. I have 3 parameter arrays (alpha, beta, sigma) that each have the size of 64.
And I have an array of randomValue with size of 10000.

My goal is to create an array of size 64 that calculates a function (NextRate) with all different randomValues for corresponding parameters. that, I can do as shown in the code by defining tid2 as the index for parameters and tid3 as the index for randomValues. here is my kernel:

```
__global__ void evaluateVasicek(KernelArray<double> crrntMonthMdlData, KernelArray<double> crrntMonthMrktData,
                            KernelArray<double> alpha, KernelArray<double> beta,
                            KernelArray<double> sigma, KernelArray<double> nextRateRands,
                            const int NP, double r0, KernelArray<double> dr)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (tid >= 640000)
     return;

  int tid2 = tid / 10000; // The index for Parameters
  int tid3 = tid % 10000; // The index for randomArray

  dr._array[tid2] += NextRate(nextRateRands._array[tid3], alpha._array[tid2], beta._array[tid2], sigma._array[tid2], r0);
  __syncthreads();

  if (tid3 == 0)
      printf("dr for tid %d is %f\n", tid2, dr._array[tid2] );

}
```

When I want to sum up all the 10000 dr's for the corresponding parameters I write the following line:

```
dr._array[tid2] += NextRate(nextRateRands._array[tid3], alpha._array[tid2], beta._array[tid2], sigma._array[tid2], r0);
__syncthreads();
```

But this seems not to work for me. I just get the last calculated value and there is no threadsync happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found the Answer I thought it is good to let others know as well.

```
__global__ void evaluateVasicek(KernelArray<double> crrntMonthMdlData, KernelArray<double> crrntMonthMrktData,
                            KernelArray<double> alpha, KernelArray<double> beta,
                            KernelArray<double> sigma, KernelArray<double> nextRateRands,
                            const int NP, double r0, KernelArray<double> dr, KernelArray<double> dr64,
                            KernelArray<double> rNext, KernelArray<double> tau, KernelArray<double> error)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (tid >= 640000)
  return;

  int tid2 = tid / 10000; // The index for Parameters
  int tid3 = tid % 10000; // The index for randomArray

  dr._array[tid] += NextRate(nextRateRands._array[tid3], alpha._array[tid2], beta._array[tid2], sigma._array[tid2], r0);
  __syncthreads();

  if (tid3 == 0) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
     dr64._array[tid2] += dr._array[tid2 * 10000 + i];


     rNext._array[tid2] = r0 + dr64._array[tid2] / 10000;
```

So basically what I did was to make dr an array of size 640000 and each thread calculates one function call.

Then, I made another array called dr64 with size of 64 and for each of the indexes for parameters (tid2) I sum up all corresponding 10000 values.